# wordpress site front page suddenly stopped working

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, wordpress

I am using minimatica theme on wordpress site. It's front page slides have suddenly stopped sliding. In console, it gives error "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" with the file "http://shuttersphotos.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3" missing / not found error. I have placed this file again and again by replacing withing the same path directory, but still gives the same console error. I have tried the same path file in local server, the file opens. But on wordpress site, the path says no page found. I am stuck, and unable to find the solution.

I have also tried by deactivating all installed and activated plugins, but nothing worked. :(

Comment: So you currently have jquery.js in your `wp-includes/js/jquery/` directory online ?

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov Yes I have.

Comment: Is very obviously not at that path,  or your htaccess won't allow serving it from that directory Can click on link generated in question and clearly see a 404 error page,

Comment: @charlietfl But the file is there. I have also checked its permissions, all set to 777. Not working, This is what making me wondered. /public_html/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js , I can see it through file manager and able to edit.

Comment: could be htacces issue , try another directory and see what happens. Look at htaccess and see if it has redirect for `js` files. Should probably be using `wp-content` directory

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried this directory to open: http://shuttersphotos.com/wp-content/uploads/ It opens it. But wp-includes , But on accessing: http://shuttersphotos.com/wp-includes it gives page not found error.

Comment: @charlietfl I have found this code on .htaccess file: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: why are you placing in `wp-includes`? Put it in `wp-content` where all your other scripts are. As I rememeber ( I don't do a lot of wordpress), should never modify `wp-includes`

Comment: @charlietfl I have placed jquery.js in wp-content/themes/minimatica/scripts directory. But the error shows that jquery.js has beend trying to be found in wp-includes.

Comment: well you have to define the path where jquery  is enqueud

Comment: I am new on wordpress, can you please tell me the exact file location code to make changes ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28197/discussion-between-sana-and-charlietfl)

Comment: need to find in theme where they have used [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Link is to docs